# I'm not certain this makes any sense: Matrix Multiplication of Metric Tensor for calculating arclength

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, mathematical-physics, tensors

I was reading: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Arclength

Where in it gives the euclidean measure of distance as

$$ ds^2 = E du^2 + 2 F du dv + G dv^2 $$

Equivalently as

$$ ds^2 =\begin{bmatrix} du &  dv \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} E & F \\ F  & G\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  du \\ dv \end{bmatrix} $$

But this blatantly false, considering that

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix} E & F \\ F  & G\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  du \\ dv \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  E du + F dv \\ F du + G dv \end{bmatrix}
$$

So then

$$ ds^2 = \begin{bmatrix} du &  dv \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  E du + F dv \\ F du + G dv \end{bmatrix} = 
$$

$$E du^2 + (E+F) du dv + F dv^2 +F du^2 + (F + G) du dv + G dv^2 =$$

$$(E+F) du^2 + (E + 2F + G) du dv +(F+G) dv^2  $$

And doesn't equate to the original at all. So what exactly are they trying to convey in this section? Obviously it's not classical matrix multiplication.

Comment: It's because you have made a mistake in your second step doing the matrix multiplication

Comment: I think it's you who isn't doing classical matrix multiplication - check that second one again.

Comment: hahaha thank god it was me

Comment: derp beautiful 4 am sillyness

Comment: You did a mistake when computing the matrix multiplication. Don't forget: you multiply a 1X2 vector by a 2x1 vector, so du multiplies Edu+F dv and dv multiplies F du + G dv